# What differences are there between the XBOX en PS version?

Tags: la-noire

I'm trying to decide whether I should buy L.A. Noire for Xbox 360 or PS3.

1) Is there a comparative review between the versions on the two consoles?

2) Has Rockstar announced any downloadable content for the game, and if so, are those items exclusive to either of the consoles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that the PS3 version does some with some (currently) exclusive DLC. Most likely the DLC will be available for the Xbox 360 version as well, but of course you'd have to pay for it.

Also, the Xbox 360 version is on 3 discs, while the PS3 version is on only 1 disc.

Comment: Ah the difference between Blu-ray and DVD storage capacity

Comment: The game is also at 720p, and the textures were downsized significantly to fit on those DVDs, so they're actually upscaling on the 360 to 1080p in an attempt to compensate.  If you have a nice television, though, the PS3 version will probably look way better.

Answer (score 2):

Digital Foundry provides a [thorough comparative review](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-la-noire-face-off). And they do favour the PS3 incarnation as well.